# Fixed Position Table Row Labels

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table in a div with overflow-x: scroll. So, you can scroll the long table left and right. The first "column" (td's in first position of each tr) should contain labels for the rows. I would like that when you scroll right or left, the contents of the table scroll, but the labels stay fixed so you can always see them.

I initially wanted to create another table to the left of this one, but the catch is the contents of each row is variable, so I don't know the height of each row until after the contents load (making it difficult to set the height of each cell in the "label column." The reason I can't dynamically just update the heights of the label column cells after the content loads is that it is really slow on FF and IE. The slowdown comes from calling clientHeight on the content tr or first td. It takes 5-6 seconds on my first clientHeight call of the content (the rest of them take 0-1ms). Regardless, I don't know of another approach.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This sort of thing has been of great interest to designers over the years, yet it remains insanely difficult to do well.  Browsers tend to be pretty weird about rendering tables ...

Comment: Maybe you could try offsetHeight instead of clientHeight? Maybe that is faster ... 5-6 seconds seems like an implementation error

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe put all the contents of your other cells into the first cell as well, at offset (0,0), so that the height of the label cell is automatically set to the height of the largest component. and then put a layer above them so that they are invisible, and put the label in there.